# How to get just a portion of the Word.Range.Text

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-2007

I'm using c#.net and word 2007 lib's

I want to be able to grab a portion of the Word.Range.Text and change it without affecting the formatting, text or anything else in the Range.

How would I go about getting a portion of the Word.Range.Text so I can change the text or even just delete that portion of the text?

example:

*I want this text edited/delete* But this portion to be left alone

Solution:
Ok, Turns out you need to have a "clone" of the paragraph and then by setting the start and end of the range within the cloned variable you are able to set where in the paragraph you want to edit. As follows:

```
Word.Range clonedRange = parag.Range;
cloneRange.Start = 0;
cloneRange.End = 15;

cloneRange.Text = "";
```

Comment: Ups! I was about to write my solution. But I guess that it is not required anymore... Basically you have to treat ranges as bits of text (string variables) and set different properties to each of them (+ a nice example). :)

Comment: hehe Thanks Varocarbas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Turns out you need to have a "clone" of the paragraph and then by setting the start and end of the range within the cloned variable you are able to set where in the paragraph you want to edit. As follows:

```
Word.Range clonedRange = parag.Range;
cloneRange.Start = 0;
cloneRange.End = 15;

cloneRange.Text = "";
```

Also Thank you to varocarbas :)